# What is the motivation for this character to hide Spider-Man's true identity in Spider-Man: Homecoming?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, character-motivation, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*,

> The Vulture (Adrian Toomes)

discovers the true identity of Spider-Man. (*Psst.. it's*

> *Peter Parker*)

After things do not go well for him and he gets arrested because of Spider-Man, he doesn't reveal the true identity of Spider-Man to the authorities or anyone from the criminal world. If he had, he could easily take revenge.

**Why does he stay silent about his enemy's true identity?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was out of gratitude for Peter saving his life

> *“That’s what is cool — **he gets a moment of redemption and he gets to
> protect Peter, even though Peter would never know. It’s his way of
> saying thank you.***
>
> *It was a really interesting thing in the development of the story. You
> couldn’t just rely on the tropes of the villain being a murderer and
> killing a bunch of people. He had to be redeemable in some capacity in
> the end and that he believes everything he said, especially about his
> family. So it was a really fine walk to create a villain that still
> has that moment of redemption in the end.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[SPIDER-MAN: HOMECOMING Director Jon Watts On That Surprising Mid-Credits Scene](https://www.comicbookmovie.com/spider-man/homecoming/spoilers-spider-man-homecoming-director-jon-watts-on-that-surprising-mid-credits-scene-a152257)</sup></sub>

Note that Toomes, for all of his flaws and bluster isn't actually motivated by evil.

> **Feige:** *“I think it is different from the other credits sequences. I think
> people are conditioned to look for a forward facing tease about what’s
> to come. But that’s not always, maybe not even half the time, what our
> gags are about. Certainly, the one at the very end of the movie is
> clearly not that. But **this was basically just meant to show that
> Toomes was not a horrible guy, had found himself in this position, and
> realized this kid saved his daughter, this kid saved his own life. He
> wouldn’t even be alive if it wasn’t for this kid. And in that moment
> where he had the opportunity to rat him out and have a guy go after
> him, he decides to keep the secret, because he appreciated ultimately
> what Peter did for him.**  He is one of the few villains to survive a
> movie, and I think you appreciate it.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Kevin Feige and Jon Watts Discuss the Credits Scene](http://www.slashfilm.com/spider-man-homecoming-credits-scene-2/)</sup></sub>